# Is there a web app for easily managing signups?

Tags: webapp-rec

I am responsible for a group of people that rotate responsibilities during the week. For example, there are tasks that must be done on Monday, Wednesday, and Friday, and there are several of us that take turns doing each (signing up to volunteer when we are available as opposed to being assigned).

I'd like to set something up online where we can individually sign up for each "slot" whenever we are available, and anyone can see at a glance who will be handling the tasks for that day (with reminders, etc).

I was thinking about trying to set something up in Google Calendar or Docs, but those aren't specifically designed for this scenario. What is the best way of handling task "signups" in a web app?

Answer (score 2):

Try [Trello](http://trello.com).

You can create cards which are the tasks and users can then assign a card to themselves or to others. Clicking on a specific card will give you the history of the changes that have occurred (ex. John assigned this card to himself). You can also set up lists such as ToDo, Doing, and Done. Cards can then be moved to each list as the status changes.